# AsyncHttpClient in Runnable

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable, asynchttpclient

In my app I need to implement some kind of chat. But instead of using longpoll connections I am just sending `get` requests to server once every 5 seconds. Chat is not primary function in my app.
I'm using `Handler` to post a `Runnable`, where in `run` method I'm using `AsyncHttpClient`.
Here's code:

```
chatHandler = new Handler();
    chatRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final int pos = adapter.getCount();
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.addHeader("X-Auth-token", User.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getToken());
            client.addHeader("clienttype", "android");
            try {
                client.addHeader("clientvesrion", (getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0)).versionName);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.add("todo_id", todo.getServerId() + "");
            params.add("from_id", messages.size() == 0 ? "0" : messages.get(messages.size() - 1).getId() + "");
            client.setTimeout(5000);

            client.get(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.server_path) + getString(R.string.path_messages_from_id), params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
                      ...
            });
        }
    };
    chatHandler.postDelayed(chatRunnable, 5000);
```

However, sometimes this crashes at `client.get()` with following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: thread creation failed
        at java.lang.VMThread.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1050)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:913)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1295)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:81)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.sendRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:893)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.get(AsyncHttpClient.java:612)
        at ru.dotcapital.controlmanager.ChatActivity$1.run(ChatActivity.java:115)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Some referenses at google says that its happening when you have lots of activities running and not finished, and lots of AsyncTasks running in one time, but my `ChatActivity` is 3rd activity.User would call and I have no AsyncTasks running in time when the error appeared.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Somehow, this error appears only when device haven't got internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the broader context from this code, but based on your question where you said you are doing something every 5 seconds, is it possible you are doing this routine even when you don't have internet? I also don't see you closing the client using the [close()](https://asynchttpclient.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/com/ning/http/client/AsyncHttpClient.html#close()) method. Not calling `close()` does not free up resources even if there is no response, and than continuous calls just fill up the memory.

Comment: Well, thanks. As i meantioned in comment below topicstarter, it only appears when device haven't got internet connection. So I added internet connection check and problem was solved.

Comment: Ok, but nevertheless, always close your client or do whatever you must for the application to work even in a invalid situation (not to crash and burn). I understand it needs internet but it leaves a bad impression if it crashes when it does not.